# FrameLayout on Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-framelayout

I am having an Issue with my Layout, I am using the following code to view a Fragment via frameLayout but the FrameLayout goes on to the Toolbar -

here's the ***main.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ab"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

& here's the Fragment Layout - 
***web.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/homefragmentFrameLayout1">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        wheel:matProg_barColor="?attr/colorAccent"
        wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ref"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

***toolbar.xml***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use RelativeLayout as root layout. It measures children twice. Same goes for LinearLayout with weights. What you did can be achieved with a FrameLayout and `android:layout_gravity`. #perfmatters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to Framelayout as well RelativeLayout in web.xml

Try this:

```
<FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/content_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: Could you post your screenshot of your screen? Try change layout to `match_parent`

Comment: Adding app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to Framelayout as well RelativeLayout in web.XML, Fixed the issue... Plzz update the answer So I can Accept it :)

Comment: Oh. I understood the reason with your clue above, app will replace `FrameLayout` with your layout(web.xml), so `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` not affect with `web.xml` layout (you can remove this line in FrameLayout and it still works).

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for the Help :)